# Security error when doing a post from a flash application to an Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, actionscript-3, security, post

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://mysite.com/Content/MyFlashApp/myflash.swf cannot load data from http://www.mysite.com/Home/SaveData.
    at Main/encodeAndSave()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/?p=115) post says that the problem can be caused by the wrong path being specified on the server side. You don't give a whole lot of information with your question - is this the problem you're having?

Other options from the same post are:

Trying to upload a file that is too big

Invalid filenames (e.g. containing an apostrophe)

A proxy server messing with the upload

Answer (score 0):

When doing a Post to a web app from a flash app, you must specify the URLRequest's server path to be the exact same as what you're on.

If you specify: 
http://www.mysite.com
http://mysite.com throws the security error above.

see [here](http://curtismorley.com/2007/08/31/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-2148/) for more details on cross-domain security issues and how to resolve them.